# Custom Authorizer not working when used with AWS Chalice

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice, lambda-authorizer

I am using AWS Custom Authorizer to secure lambda function. I am not able to use the custom authorizer because of some configurational issues.

when I tried attaching the authorizer from API Gateway Console, it is working fine. When the authorizer is attached from code, it is not giving any error. I tried checking the cloudwatch logs, the logs are not generated for lambda functions(both for authorizer and helloworld function).

Below is a sample code which I have written:

```
from chalice import Chalice
from chalice import CustomAuthorizer
app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld-python')

authorizer = CustomAuthorizer(
    'MyCustomAuth', header='Authorization',
    authorizer_uri=('arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31'
                    '/functions/arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account-id}:'
                    'function:{function-name}/invocations'))

@app.route('/test/test_authorizer', authorizer=authorizer)
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

I have configured the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "execute-api:Invoke"
        ],
        "Resource": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am not able to add the authorizer to the lambda function. When I fire the endpoint it is giving me following error:

> End Point:
>   https://{rest-api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/dev/test/test_authorizer
>
> Http method: GET
>
> Error Code: 500.
>
> Error body: `{
>       "message": null 
>   }`

How can I achieve this. Please provide me with the proper intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue: https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/670#issuecomment-573637135

Alternatively, there is a workaround

1. Open Aws Console
2. Go to Amazon API Gateway,
3. On the right side click on 'Authorizers'
4. Click 'Edit' Authorizer
5. Click on save and Test it again.